# Sprites in LESSC

Tags: less, css-sprites

Is there an addon to LESSC that would allow me to to do something like:

LESS

```
.icon-xyz{ .sprite('image1.png'); }
.icon-abc{ .sprite('image2.png'); }
```

that outputs a merged sprite in production mode, and stays with the individual images in development mode?

Similar to how Compass works with SASS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some addon for node.js: less-sprites. https://github.com/polycode/less-sprites

It requires install  ImageMagick firstly.